# Get all templates django detects from TEMPLATE_LOADERS and TEMPLATE_DIRS

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/path/to/templates/',)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I'm trying to find a solution that would list the contents of my specified directory in either of these locations (`TEMPLATE_DIRS` or `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`).

I need something like:

```python
template_files = []
for dir in EVERY_DIRECTORY_DJANGO_LOOKS_FOR_TEMPLATES_IN:
    template_files.append(os.listdir(dir))
```

Comment: would `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS + settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS` not work ?

Comment: I can iterate over settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS, but settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS is just a tuple of modules, not dirs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since templates can be in nested directories under the base template locations I would recommend using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to get the templates you require, it is essentially a wrapper for `os.listdir` that will follow directories.

`django.template.loaders.app_directories.app_template_dirs` is an internal tuple of all app template directories and `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is a setting that is used by `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader`.

The following code should generate a list of all available files in your template directories (this could include non template files):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loaders.app_directories import app_template_dirs

import os

template_files = []
for template_dir in (settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS + app_template_dirs):
    for dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(template_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            template_files.append(os.path.join(dir, filename))
```

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone is still needing this, I'm running 1.9.2 and it looks like
`app_template_dirs` is now `get_app_template_dirs` and `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS` is now `settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']`

Here's what I did:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loaders.app_directories import get_app_template_dirs
import os

template_dir_list = []
for template_dir in get_app_template_dirs('templates'):
    if settings.ROOT_DIR in template_dir:
        template_dir_list.append(template_dir)


template_list = []
for template_dir in (template_dir_list + settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']):
    for base_dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(template_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            template_list.append(os.path.join(base_dir, filename))
```

Then you can iterate through the list as you need using template_list:

```
for template in template_list:
    print template
```

Comment: Note that, while this may be useful, ``template_list`` is a list of pathnames that identifies the files used by the DjangoTemplates backend assuming it is the first of the TEMPLATES settings. Other templates may be accessible via other backends and they may or may not make use of other files.

There is no way in Django to use the template backends ('loaders' for older django versions) to list all possible template names because listing the names is not defined in the template backend protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Using Django's template loaders to return a list of all paths, then pathlib to blob (recursively) down each dir to find all `.html` files:

```
from pathlib import Path

from django import template as django_template


def get_all_templates_files():
    dirs = []
    for engine in django_template.loader.engines.all():
        # Exclude pip installed site package template dirs
        dirs.extend(x for x in engine.template_dirs if 'site-packages' not in str(x))
    files = []
    for dir in dirs:
        files.extend(x for x in Path(dir).glob('**/*.html') if x)
    return files
```

Comment: so far the only one that actually works with django 3.x