# Get all html templates in django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get the list of html name templates on a template folder in views?

eg. `app/templates
          ----> sample.html
          ----> sample2.html`

Comment: Is this just for a specific app? What will you be using the list for?

Comment: Please add more context to your question so we can understand what your problem really is.

Comment: well given that we have a sample app in that app there are built-in files from Django which is views.py, urls.py, templates. now in my view, I have created a function and in that function, I want to get the list of templates that are in the template folder. I want to use the list for the sitemap framework. thanks for the replies @IainShelvington

Comment: For a sitemap it probably makes more sense to look at the urls? Templates can be shared by many different views and views can be shared by many different urls

Comment: to make it more general we only used one view passing arg the "template name" eg. index.html and render it. I have already populated the sitemap by hardcoding the list of templates but it would be good to get all templates if ever in future we will add more pages. @IainShelvington

Comment: @markbrainhub do you want to get all templates in a specific folder/app or do you want to get every template in the entire project? You can probably just walk through the folder(s) and filter by ".html" extension

Comment: @IainShelvington yes I want to get all the templates in a specific folder eg. app/templates. can this be done using the django framework like template loaders?

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago, this would give you all available templates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111822/get-all-templates-django-detects-from-template-loaders-and-template-dirs/17113087#17113087. To get the templates from just one directory you could modify the answer to only look in the directory you want

Comment: I can use that but would require me to reconfigure the way how my templates are loaded in settings. thanks for the help @IainShelvington.